# Get a bundle name from an entity

Tags: symfony

How can you get the bundle's name from an entity?

is there any function or service to get this?

```
$artist = new Artist();

$bundleName = artist->getBundleName();

echo  $bundleName
```

> myCompanyArtistBundle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution but don't know if it's a good one :

```
<?php
    $rootEntityName = "company\myNamespace\Entity\user";

    $bundles = $context->get('kernel')->getBundles();
    $bundleName = '';

    foreach($bundles as $type=>$bundle){
        $className = get_class($bundle);

        $entityClass = substr($rootEntityName,0,strpos($rootEntityName,'\\Entity\\'));

        if(strpos($className,$entityClass)=== FALSE){
            echo get_class($bundle).'<br>';
            echo $type.'<br>';
        }else{
            $bundleName = $type;
        }
    }
    echo $bundleName;
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer this solution :

```
/**
 * Get the bundle name from an Entity namespace
 *
 * @return string
 * @author lenybernard
 **/
protected static function getBundleNameFromEntity($entityNamespace, $bundles)
{
    $dataBaseNamespace = substr($entityNamespace, 0, strpos($entityNamespace, '\\Entity\\'));
    foreach ($bundles as $type => $bundle) {
        $bundleRefClass = new \ReflectionClass($bundle);
        if ($bundleRefClass->getNamespaceName() === $dataBaseNamespace) {
            return $type;
        }
    }
}
```

Nota bene : the `$bundles` variable is the result of calling the getBundles() method on the `kernel` service.