# How to get current bundle in Symfony 2?

Tags: symfony

How can I detect in which bundle am I?

for exemple, when I'm in web.com/participants/list, I want to read "participants".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AFAIK it's not yet possible (at least in a easy way). You should use reflection. I wrote a quick and dirty service to do get bundle name ang guess entity/repository/form names based on my conventions. Can be buggy, take a look at: http://pastebin.com/BzeXAduH

It works only when you pass a class that inherits from Controller (Symfony2). Usage:

```
entity_management_guesser:
  class: Acme\HelloBundle\Service\EntityManagementGuesser
```

In your controller:

```
$guesser = $this->get('entity_management_guesser')->inizialize($this);

$bundleName  = $guesser->getBundleName();      // Acme/HelloBundle
$bundleShort = $guesser->getBundleShortName(); // AcmeHelloBundle
```

Another possibility would be using kernel to get all bundles: [Get a bundle name from an entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9519471/get-a-bundle-name-from-an-entity)

Comment: It's been 2.5 years since the response, anyone heard of any advancements yet on the question? :) Is there a "cleaner" way to find the bundle name? :)

Answer (score 15):

In order to get the **bundle name** in the controller:

```
// Display "AcmeHelloBundle"
echo $this->getRequest()->attributes->get('_template')->get('bundle');
```

And inside a Twig template:

```
{{ app.request.get('_template').get('bundle') }}
```

In order to get the **controller name** in the controller:

```
// Display "Default"
echo $this->getRequest()->attributes->get('_template')->get('controller');
```

And inside a Twig template:

```
{{ app.request.get('_template').get('controller') }}
```

In order to get the **action name** in the controller:

```
// Displays "index"
echo $this->getRequest()->attributes->get('_template')->get('name');
```

And inside a Twig template:

```
{{ app.request.get('_template').get('name') }}
```

Comment: pretty sure `->attributes->get('_template')` isn't available if you don't use the @template annotation.

Comment: you may use `$request->attributes->get('_controller');` or `$this->getRequest()->attributes->get('_controller');` in controller to grab controller name.

Answer (score 6):

Well you can get the controller of the current route by,

```
$request->attributes->get('_controller');
```

You can parse the bundle name from it.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the bundle name in the **controller** simply like that:

```
// Display "SybioCoreBundle"
echo $this->getRequest()->attributes->get('_template')->get('bundle');
```

And inside a **Twig template**:

```
{{ app.request.get('_template').get('bundle') }}
```